# Using jquery, how can I make a timer that can be immediately restarted and counts down visibly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, setinterval

[Current jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MaxMeents/60omkjas/)

the main problem has been clearing, no matter what I do the interval seems to run multiple timers for each click even though I clear

I've been at it all night.
I simply would like to restart a countdown timer on click. 
I'm trying to give the person 5 seconds to prepare 
and then 7 seconds to do the action.
so, it needs to countdown from 5 then countdown from 7 and at anytime if clicked it needs to start completely over.

Its much harder than it sounds.

I used a combo of

```
clearInterval()
var Interval = setInterval(function(){}, 1000);
```

but could never get it to work.

Comment: You should provide the id returned by `setInterval` to `clearInterval`, i.e. `clearInterval(Interval)`

Comment: thank you for commenting but I did that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
var timer = (function() {
    var timer = null;

    return {
        start: function( timesToRun, callback, interval ) {
            var timesRan = 0
            timer = setInterval( function() {
                if ( timesRan < timesToRun ) {
                    timesRan++
                    callback( timesRan, timesRan === timesToRun )
                } else {
                    clearInterval( timer )
                }
            }, interval || 1000 )

            return this 
        },

        stop: function() {
            clearInterval( timer )

            return this
        }
    }
}())

var cyclesLabel = document.getElementById("t")

// first argument is the amount of times to run the interval
// second argument is a callback to use on each iteration
// the 3rd argument is optional and is the interval time in milliseconds.
timer.start( 7, totalCycles, 1000 )

// Reset example
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener( "click", function() {
   cyclesLabel.textContent = "0"
   timer.stop().start( 5, totalCycles )
} )

// Just for the sake of the example
function totalCycles( cycles, lastCycle ) {
   cyclesLabel.textContent = cycles

   if ( lastCycle === true ) {
     alert( "This is the last chance to do something" )
   }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eedny9jn/2/

Comment: I wish I could write code so pretty and complicated with such ease

Comment: Nothing special here, You just need to read a book or two to strengthen you js knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

setTimeout() returns an identifier you can use to cancel the request:

```
var timerId = setTimeout(function() { console.log('Now!'); }, 5000);
```

Then you can cancel it later, unless it already has been executed:

```
$('#cancelTimerButton').click(function() {  clearTimeout(timerId); });
```

If you need to visualize it you can do something like this:

```
var n = 0;
var tick = function() {
    console.log(n % 2 ? 'Tock' : 'Tick');
    timerId = setTimeout(tick, 1000);
    if (++n == 5) {
        clearTimeout(timerId);
    }
};
var timerId = setTimeout(tick, 1000);`
```

Comment: how would you count down visually with setTimeout?

Comment: You could use 1 second (1000 millis) and keep a counter?